# Equivalent conditions for reducibility of $\mathbb{C}$-linear operator on ${\mathbb{C}}^n$

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, complex-analysis, linear-transformations, invariant-subspace

Let $A$ be a $\mathbb{C}$-linear operator from ${\mathbb{C}}^n$ to itself, with rank$A=p < n$.

For complex linear subspace $E$ of ${\mathbb{C}}^n$, $A$ is called reduced by $E$ if both $E$ and $E^{\bot}$ are invariant subspaces of $A$.

Note that $A$ induces the orthogonal decompositions

$$
{\mathbb{C}}^n = \text{Ran}A\oplus\text{Ker}A^* =\text{Ran}A^*\oplus\text{Ker}A.
$$

Then we claim the following characterization of reducibility of $A$ by Ran$A$ :

> Proposition) The following conditions are equivalent
>
> i) Ran$A$ reduces $A$
>
> ii) Ran$A$ = Ran$A^* $, and Ker$A$ = Ker$A^*$
>
> iii) $A$ commutes with the orthogonal projection onto Ran$A$
>
> iv) there exists a unitary operator $U : {\mathbb{C}}^n \rightarrow {\mathbb{C}}^n$ and
> a $\mathbb{C}$-linear isomorphism $B : {\mathbb{C}}^p \rightarrow {\mathbb{C}}^p$ such that, for all $(z,w)\in{\mathbb{C}}^p\times{\mathbb{C}}^{n-p},$
> $$ \left(B(z),0\right) = UAU^*(z,w).$$

How can I prove this?

Note: this is lemma 3.1.10 from "Pluripotential Theory" by Klimek.

Answer (score 0):

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xFfKu.jpg)

I hope this answers your question.

Comment: Please do not use pictures for critical portions of your post. Pictures may not be legible, cannot be searched and are not view-able to some, such as those who use screen readers.